# List Template & difference between List Template & List Defnition

Tags: c#, sharepoint, list, templates, definition

Can anyone tell me please how to customize **list template** in visual studio pro grammatically? & What is the **core difference** between *List Definition & List Template*. how they are used in SharePoint Sites.

As i am beginner.

Thanks in Advance
Kishan

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these two pages:

[Managing List Templates programmatically](http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/Managing-Save--Delete-List-Templates-programmatically-in-SharePoint-176.php)

[SharePoint glossary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee413946.aspx)

Comment: Thanx Vedran , I got your point. one part of Question is clear. but the link you gave of List template is of saving & deleting. I am asking if suppose i have customize my list template through .stp file , then how it's possible ?? if you any project or solution ? please kindly help me out.Thanx In advance